# How can I make this VB code work in C# using the same variable?

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

I'm trying to figure out how to convert the following sample code to C# using the same implicit define as VB. I know I can define the button and generic control as two objects and make it work, but I would like to use the same variable "ctlHTML" in C# just like VB works. Can someone help on this?

```
Sub MySub(varInput As String, pnl As Panel)
    Dim ctlHTML = Nothing
    Select Case varInput
        Case "btn"
            ctlHTML = New HtmlButton
        Case "lbl"
            ctlHTML = New HtmlGenericControl()
    End Select
    With ctlHTML
        .Style.Add("font-size", "14px")
    End With
    pnl.Controls.Add(ctlHTML)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You won't be able to directly convert the code. You'll have to give your variable a type. The class highest in the inheritance chain that supports all of your members would be `HtmlControl`:

```
HtmlControl control = null;
switch(varInput)
{
    case "btn":
        control = new HtmlButton();
        break;
    case "lbl":
        control = new HtmlGenericControl();
        break;
}

if(control != null)
{
    control.Style.Add("font-size", "14px");
    pnl.Controls.Add(control);
}
```

Comment: If only two cases, I would use ternary expression and lose the switch.

Comment: @YoryeNathan - I'm not going to make any assumptions about the actual code. This could only be an example. If the OP wants to make optimizations, they can be done later.

Comment: Didn't suggest a change in the answer, just provided extra info that might be helpful to the OP, in addition to your answer.

Comment: Thank you. I overlooked the HtmlControl somehow.

Answer (score 4):

In order to modify the `Style` property, the control at minimum needs to be an `HtmlControl`. So you need to declare the variable `ctlHtml` as that type.

You should also check to make sure the `ctlHtml` is properly initialized.

I believe your code should look something like this:

```
public void MySub(string varInput, Panel pnl)
{
    HtmlControl ctlHtml;
    switch(varInput)
    {
        case "btn":
            ctlHtml = new HtmlButton();
            break;
        case "lbl":
            ctlHtml = new HtmlGenericControl();
            break;
        default:
            ctlHtml = null;
            break;
    }
    if (ctlHtml != null)
    {
        ctlHtml.Style.Add("font-size", "14px");
        pnl.Controls.Add(ctlHtml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `HtmlGenericControl` and `HtmlButton` both inherit from `HtmlControl`, you can declare ctlHTML as that type (`HtmlControl`) and it will work.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlcontrol.aspx